# Javascript regular expression for parsing information giving from PING command

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

I have a script that gets the output after a ping, the output looks like this:

```
var input = "PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.065/0.067/0.073/0.010 ms"
```

I was first trying to get how many packets that was transmitted. So I tried with this regular expression: (\d+)*\spackets

Basically to match on the "NUMBER packets" it seems to work on this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html but I can't replicate it.

And when using the regular expression with match, it also fails, like this:

```
"42 packets".match('(\d+)*\spackets');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript regex must be surrounded by forward slash delimiters to indicate a RegExp object, not quotes:

```
"42 packets".match(/(\d+)\spackets/);
```

Which is short form for:

```
"42 packets".match(new RegExp('(\d+)\spackets'));
```

Comment: I see, thanks! What about the string "0% packet loss" by matching on the %, or what about "0.065/0.067/0.073/0.010"?

Comment: If you want to use quotes, you use the `new RegExp("pattern goes here")` syntax and escape your backslashes. Not really the greatest way of inputting a regex, but it is doable.

Comment: `/(\d+)%\spacket loss/` for the first, and `/(?:(\d+\.\d+)(?:\/|\sms))+/` for the second to capture each number in a separate group.

Answer (score 2):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) takes a regular expression object, not a string.

```
"42 packets".match(/(\d+)\spackets/);
```

In addition, you don't need the `*` -- `\d+` matches one or more number characters, <del>so looking for zero or more groups of one or more integers is redundant in your case</del> and `*` actually means that you can have **0** or more groups of one or more integers ... which means, as Paul points out, that you could have a match on `packets` alone.

Comment: Not just redundant ;) It means his regex will match " packets" with no number in front. Which is probably not what he wants :)

Comment: @Paul - absolutely true.  Redacting :-)